# What does Mod^(1,0) mean in mathematica output

Tags: modular-arithmetic, calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to take he derivative of mod(remainder).

```
In:= D[Mod[x, y], x]
Out = Mod^(1,0)[x,y]
```

I cannot understand the meaning of Mod^(1,0). What does the exponential actually mean ?

Comment: It means the derivative with respect to the first argument. Look up `Derivative[]`.

Comment: Look at the `FullForm` of your result or evaluate `D[Mod[x, y], x] // FullForm`

Comment: I'm not sure about the "easily found in the documentation" part :)  The notation is described explicitly in [Derivatives of Unknown Functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DerivativesOfUnknownFunctions.html).  A broader discussion can be found in [The Representation of Derivatives](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheRepresentationOfDerivatives.html).